# How to backup a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, backup, push

I want to periodically backup a Mercurial repository to the bitbucket clone. One option is to schedule it with cron. But fail to see how to 'add' and then 'push' from the cron configuration file (how to execute 'hg' in the local directory?).

A line like this in the crontab

```
*/60 * * * * ~/path/to/repository/hg push https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repository
```

does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the full qualified path in cron scripts, ~ is not expanded to the home directory.

However the way you quote looks funky. You can call hg and directly specify the path to the repository:

```
hg -R /full/path/to/repository push URL
```

Thus

```
*/60 * * * * hg -R /full/path/to/repository push URL
```

might do the trick for you.

Comment: Gosh! Forgot to specify the `-v` option in the help command to get to know about that `-R` argument.  Thx!